# select action occurs befor insert postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

I'm dealing with a problem that I can't solve. I've got 2 tables `users` and `login`. The `users` table keeps all my user's info and the `login` table keeps the `user's emails and hashes`:

**Backend code:**

```js
const handleRegister = (req, res, db, bcrypt, saltRounds) => {
const { email, first_name, last_name, password } = req.body;
// creating hash for password
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
// form validation
if ( !email || !first_name || !last_name || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
}
// updating login and users tables in the database
db.transaction(trx => {
    trx.insert({
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email,
        joined: new Date()  
    })
    .into('users')
    .returning('email')
    .then(loginEmail => {
        return trx('login')
            .returning('email')
            .insert ({
                hash: hash,
                email: loginEmail[0] 
            })
            .then(userEmail => {
                db.select('*').from('users').where('email', userEmail[0])                   
                .then(user => {
                    userInfo = Object.assign(user[0], {lists: []} , {tasks: []});
                    res.json({user: userInfo});                     
                    })
                .catch(err => {res.status(400).json('unable to get user')})
            })              
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json('unable to register');
        console.log(err);
    })
```

At first, when I tried to add a new user through `Postman` everything was ok, but when I tried to add another user, I got an error:

```
 "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
```

Because for some reason the db.select in line 28 does not get any result and passes user=[].
The thing is that when I check my database, the user that I just added is there. So, it looks like it's doing the db.select in line 28 before the insert in line 23.

Comment: I don't follow your code at all, but the general strategy you should use here is `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`, that is, use a single insert query which first checks whether or not that user already exists.  Or, you may add a unique constraint on the username.

Comment: thank you for your comment. my problem is that for some reason this line: db.select('*').from('users').where('email', userEmail[0]) occurs befor the insert so it doesnt return any user because the user wasn't insert yet. after that i checked my database and saw that the user was insert as expected.. is it possible? that it occurs before even though its after .then ?